# Java try with resource inputstream null check

Tags: java, inputstream, try-with-resources

Can somebody help on try with resource in java

```
try(InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(some file)))
{
     if(inputStream == null)       //Line 3
     {
      }
}
catch(IOException e)
{
}
```

I want to know, is it necessary to check null on line 3. Will there be any situation or circumstances where inputStream can be null at line 3 ?

Comment: Not in this case, but in cases like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372148/try-with-resource-when-autocloseable-is-null

Comment: @takendarkk will the execution come to line 3 if inputstream is null or it will escape from try catch without any error?

Comment: Not sure. You can just set the variable to null and run it to see.

Comment: `new Anything()` is never, ever null.

Comment: @Community, reopened, `new FileInputStream` never returns `null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given your code, no:

`InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(some file))` will be executed before the contents of the `try` block. Either it will succeed, so `inputStream` will not be `null`, or it will fail, throwing an exception in the process, so the contents of the `try` block will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know, is it necessary to check null on line 3.

No. As long as you keep the expression `new FileInputStream(new File("path/to/file"))`, the result will be a non-null object of `FileInputStream`. The check on line 3 is unnecessary.

> Will there be any situation or circumstances where inputStream can be null at line 3?

Yes. If you assign any expression that returns `null` to `inputStream`. It's not really practical since you can't do anything with the stream except for checking it on null. In that case, the check on line 3 may come in handy.

For example,

```
try (InputStream s = null) {}
catch (IOException e) {}
```